# How to treat all matching elements as a set?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to convert, tweak, treat elements containing the same class as a set?

```
<div class="f">fgfgh</div>
<div class="f">dfg</div>
<div class="f">qzer</div>

<script> 
function _(c){ 
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(c);
    return x; 
};
_("f")[all_of_them_not_0_1].innerHTML = "changed"; 
</script>
```

I could definitely loop through them, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Why throw loops out the window, they're there for a reason

Comment: You should look into jQuery. It's functional syntax is a perfect match.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.f');`, then loop. Or document.querySelectorAll().

Comment: Please take a look at this solution and tell me if it meets your needs https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/a7yuzz3z/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to add `Element.prototype` methods to `HTMLCollection.prototype`. However, be aware of that!!

```
var elementMethods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Element.prototype);
elementMethods.forEach(attachElementMethodsToHTMLCollection);
function attachElementMethodsToHTMLCollection(methodName) {
    HTMLCollection.prototype[methodName] = function() {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (methodName !== 'innerHTML' && typeof Element.prototype[methodName] === 'function') {
                result.push(Element.prototype[methodName].apply(this.item(i), arguments))
            } else {
                result.push(arguments.length ? this.item(i)[methodName] = arguments[0] : this.item(i)[methodName])
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
};
```

Then:

```
function _(c) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(c);
};
_("f").innerHTML('HTML !')
_("f").setAttribute('title', 'My title')
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/a7yuzz3z/

Answer (score 5):

This isn't about JavaScript, but rather the DOM API.

No, there aren't set-based mutation operations (setting `innerHTML`, for instance) built into the DOM API. You have to loop through the elements (or use something that does so for you behind the scenes, like jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add a class to them like class="f changed" and then with css:

```
.f.changed:after {
  content:'changed';
  display:block;
  /* any other stylings you need for this */
}
```

Then all you need to do is add or remove the class when you want to toggle the text? Not sure what you have against looping, but this is sort of one way.